# Retrieving data from instagram api using python

Tags: python, api, location, instagram

im trying to familiarise myself with using the instagram api with python, for some reason the code doesnt work and keeps on showing an error.

All i want the code to do is to compile and show me the details of location , based on their id , longtitude and latitude

```
import urllib2
import json

def testCollect(Access_token):
Access_token = '****'
latitude = '****'
longtitude = '****'
Full_URL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=' + latitude + '&lng=' + longtitude
LoadURL = urllib2.urlopen(Full_URL)
jsonData = json.load(LoadURL)

print jsonData
```

Thank you :)

Comment: There's a perfectly good Python library for the Instagram api, have you tried it?